# Are there any bundlers out there that bundle HTML templates?

Tags: html, node.js, webpack, bundler

I would like to build a static website meaning I don't need any application to dynamically render the HTML. This website can be just plain flat html/js/css files.

But this site contains many re-usable components like headers, footers, menus and other types of things that I would like to not repeat over and over on every single HTML file. I would like to have re-usability but I also don't want some application to piece the HTML files together on every request.

My goal is to just have a bundling process, like webpack, piece the HTML files together from templates and then publish them as static HTML which I can host on some CDN (content delivery network) for cheap.

I would like to avoid javascript frameworks like react/vue/angular/etc.. that pieces the view together after loading the javascript.  I would rather all HTML be present on the first request. Thats why I would like the HTML to be rendered during a bundling process.

I'm not doing anything fancy like a single page app. This is a traditional HTML website with static pages. The only javascript I would need is just for simple things like showing and hiding dom elements or animating a menu opening. I'm trying to make this site very light weight but I would like to make use of modern technologies to bundle/minify/template/etc if possible.

I really enjoy dotnet razor views and how it allows you to create templates and partial views to re-use html. But the problem with dotnet razor is that it renders the HTML on every request and requires the application to run on a web app server.

Is there anything out there like dotnet razor but bundles your HTML pages together as a build process?

I've googled and bunch and couldn't find anything.

Comment: I think something like [pug mixins](https://pugjs.org/language/mixins.html) is what you are looking for

Comment: [Wyam](https://wyam.io/) is the only Razor based Static Site Generator I know of. For others who don't have your requirement of avoiding front end frameworks, [here](https://jamstack.org/generators/) is a wonderful list of a couple static site generators.